# How to wrap or break a word which already includes multiple hyphens in CSS?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, word-break

I'm looking to wrap or break a word that has multiple hyphens like "face-to-face" or "all-or-nothing". Those kinds of words and expression do not seem to break naturally in HTML.

The only success I had when trying different combinations was with word-break:break-all but it does not break the word on any hyphens and often leave a letter alone on one line.

Here's an example:

```
<style>
.two-hyphens {
width: 10px;
font-size: 40px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>

<div class="two-hyphens">
Face to face
<br><br>
Face-to-face
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
.breakAtHyphen {
  word-break: keep-all;
}
```

Make sure you assign this class to your tag containing the text.

Here's a resource that should help with understanding the `word-break` property: [CSS Word-Break Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

Comment: Given that: the behaviour of `word-break: keep-all` is described as "*[word] breaks should not be used for Chinese/Japanese/Korean (CJK) text. Non-CJK text behavior is the same as for normal.*" I'm a little surprised that this solves the issue (reference: [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Based on the example on w3schools I posted in the answer, the example they provide specifically deals with breaking at hyphens. However, it is very interesting that breaks don't work with CJK text. Learn something new every day!

Comment: I tried `word-break: keep-all` but it doesn't work. Maybe there are other tags on higher levels that may interfere? I tried on many levels but to no success. 
I found that wrapping the hyphen in a div with `display:inline-block` properties did the trick and worked everywhere.

Comment: @johnnyg0 If you post the code where the text is I may be able to help a little more. If you're going to, make sure to post both the HTML and CSS

Comment: @lime I just added an example of code where it does not work. I found a workaround which I posted below. It works but its a little clunky. Maybe you have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using javascript or jquery? try to use replace to replace -

Answer (score 0):

I found that wrapping the hyphen in a div with display:inline-block properties seems to be doing the trick.

```
face<div style="display: inline-block;">-</div>to<div style="display: inline-block;">-</div>face<br>
```

Still I wonder if there are better ways to do this.